# In Rust is there any way to include static variables into other files?

Tags: rust, static

## Static variables and Rust

Recently I've been working on a benchmarking suite, my goals were to reduce code repetition across various benchmarking suites as they share quite a few of the tests as static variables, however, these are defined in each benchmark separately, even if they are the same variable.

I'm a little bit confused by static types in Rust and so am kinda unaware if they essentially act as global variables or not.

I was wondering whether I could simply insert a module that would avoid having to redefine these static variables. Specifically, could I just create a module and import the specific variables that I would require, i.e. similar to how Python handles `imports`.

Comment: Just put your statics in a module and import them where you need them?

Comment: Is it really just as simple as that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm a little bit confused by static types in Rust and so am kinda unaware if they essentially act as global variables or not.

Static variables are placed in the data section of the binary. They get loaded into memory when the program is started and will remain there until the program exits.

It sounds like you just need to use static variables and import them anywhere that they are needed.